# Table level logic Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Sesion(models.Model):
    maq = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ini_sesion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fin_sesion = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    cont_ini_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    con_ini_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    con_fin_a = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    con_fin_b = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

   @staticmethod
   def cierre():
    instance = Sesion.objects.filter(fin_sesion__isnull=True).latest('ini_sesion')
    sesion_abierta = None
    try:
        sesion_abierta = Sesion.objects.filter(maq=instance.maq).filter(fin_sesion__isnull=True) \
                .filter(ini_sesion__lt=instance.ini_sesion).latest('ini_sesion')
    except Exception:
        print('Ha ocurrido una excepcion!')
    if sesion_abierta:
        sesion_abierta.con_fin_a = instance.con_fin_a
        sesion_abierta.con_fin_b = instance.con_fin_b
        sesion_abierta.fin_sesion = instance.ini_sesion
    return sesion_abierta.save()
```

---

Now the thing is i can't make it work every time a model instance is saved. I works when it is called from python/django shell
`>>> Sesion.cierre()`
but not when a model instance is saved and it doesn't work on save() override or signals either. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will answer the question. Here is what worked:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Sesion)
def cierre(*args, **kwargs):
instance = Sesion.objects.filter(fin_sesion__isnull=True).latest('ini_sesion')
sesion_abierta = None
try:
    sesion_abierta = Sesion.objects.filter(maq=instance.maq).filter(fin_sesion__isnull=True) \
            .filter(ini_sesion__lt=instance.ini_sesion).latest('ini_sesion')
except Exception:
    print('Ha ocurrido una excepcion!')
if sesion_abierta:
    sesion_abierta.con_fin_a = instance.con_fin_a
    sesion_abierta.con_fin_b = instance.con_fin_b
    sesion_abierta.fin_sesion = instance.ini_sesion
    sesión_abierta.save()
```

Edit: Note that the "signals" code goes on the same line of indentation as
class Sesion(models.Model):